# How to filter by the highest count?

Tags: sql, count

I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.p#, P.PName, P.CITY
FROM P, SP, S
WHERE SP.P# = P.P#
ORDER BY P.PNAME;
```

That results in

```
P2  Bolt    Paris
P5  Cam     Paris
P6  Cog     London
P1  Nut     London
P3  Screw   Rome
P4  Screw   London
```

How can I filter it so the max count (london) is the only result? It should look like

```
P6  Cog     London
P1  Nut     London
P4  Screw   London
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses window functions:

```
select p#, pname, city
from (
    select p.*, rank() over(order by cnt desc) rn
    from (
        select p.*, count(*) over(partition by city) cnt 
        from p
    ) p
) p
where rn = 1
```

If your database supports the `fetch` clause with option `with ties` (or an equivalent syntax), we can dispense one level of nesting:

```
select p#, pname, city
from (
    select p.*, count(*) over(partition by city) cnt 
    from p
) p
order by rank() over(order by cnt desc)
fetch first row with ties
```

I don't see the points for the joins and `distinct` in the original query. All the columns you select come from `p`, so this is the only table I used in the queries.